# Cannot open database "ServicesDb" requested by the login in local machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, fluent-nhibernate, ninject

I have this error pop up in the last couple days. I was following [Asp.Net Mvc 4 and the Web Api: Building a REST Service from Start to Finish](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/1430249773/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d7_i1?pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=center-4&pf_rd_r=1KXZ9YM57HSCWE94YN7C&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1375923642&pf_rd_i=915398) on how to build a Rest Service API then along the way, came this:

> Cannot open database "ServicesDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'my-PC\my'.

So I stopped for a while and read the book and nothing. So I downloaded the [book companion project](https://github.com/jamiekurtz/Mvc4ServicesBook) and when I run it, I encounter the same error as with my own service.

This is a shock for me, as I have always used `Windows Authentication` for local database engine. I have had no problems when I have used [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework), so I am beginning to think that this has something to do with [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) and [Fluent Nhibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) which I am using for the first time.

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ServicesDb" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
         <!-- connectionString="Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0; <----- Tried this too -->
          initial catalog=ServicesDb;
          Integrated Security=True;
          Application Name=Services API Website" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Has anyone else ran into this problem while following this book? Does anyone know what could be causing this, and how I can get passed it?

**UPDATE**: Here is the code that fails to execute, the book uses Ninject and so am i.

```
private void ConfigureNHibernate(IKernel container)
        {
            // Build the NHibernate ISessionFactory object
            var sessionFactory = FluentNHibernate //Fails here, sessionFactory variable not instantiated.
                .Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
                        c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ServicesDb")))
                .CurrentSessionContext("web")
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SqlCommandFactory>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();

            // Add the ISessionFactory instance to the container
            container.Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(sessionFactory); //sessionFactory needed here

            // Configure a resolver method to be used for creating ISession objects
            container.Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(CreateSession);

            container.Bind<ICurrentSessionContextAdapter>().To<CurrentSessionContextAdapter>();
        }
```

Comment: I never had problems with Integrated Security = True for nhibernate

Comment: Perhaps try the connection string with a simple `SqlConnection` and see if it works.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I found out that the database name is written in several files: Settings.settings, App.config, DataClasses1.dbml
the weird thing is my program runs (and on the correct DB) but the error message is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in both cases i was assuming that the database was there. This is because in Visual Studio, the connection string throws a shadow of the application's database in Server Explorer. And because of that and the fact that in the past i have worked with Entity Framework Code First, which uses Migration and took care of all my SQL stuff for me.

I opened Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and confirm that the database was indeed there. When i realised that it was there, i created it and made sure that it matched my connection string. After that all was good and i could execute my SQL scripts within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Asp.Net Core Web API. Previously I had the Entity Framework take care of managing the database creation. When I recently started a new project I noticed it did not create a database for me when I checked through my SQL Server Explorer. When I tried to post data it was giving the error Login failed. Add in the browser i was only getting a blank page when I use the GET verb.

I used the Package Manager Console to invoke the following commands:

1. Add-Migrations
2. Update-Database

Hope it works for someone as well